# Magento2 - How to add a block to footer

Tags: magento2, blocks, footer

how can I add a custom block to the footer. I want to add a new block with new links next to the existing block with the contact links etc and show them beside the default block of the Luma template.

Thanks.

Comment: In Magento 2.0 ?

Comment: Yes in Magento 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it now by creating a new block in the reference of the footer container of my module default.xml.

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_company_links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links" after="footer_company_links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>    

        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="html/copyright.phtml"/>

    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Weird, all this did was remove the footer entirely for me.

Answer (score 1):

create `default.xml` in `[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/` and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="2custom-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Links</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">page-url</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

finally flush cache and run it. If you have own block then define class name as your block name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm looking for a code to add a new block with new links next to the existing block with the contact links etc.

Answer (score 1):

call custom block and links in footer in magento 2

In this article we will learn how to call links and custom block in footer in magento 2.

So, the file which is used to define configurations of footer is `default.xml`. This file will be located under **app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/layout/**. This file calls on every page, that’s why we write code for footer in this file.

Below code is used to call custom links in footer :

Custom Link
      
      path/to/page

Now If you want to add your own custom block and template inside the footer,
then below code will be used :

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
  <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="custom_block" as="custom_block" template="custom.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

That’s all in this article, hope it will help you to call custom block and links inside footer. Try the above code and if you have any issue just comment below.